# Advice on how to hook into a client-side "word typed" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

So i'm working on something where i want to fire off an event (client-side, JavaScript) in two scenarios:

- If the user has finished typing a word, e.g: "stack " (fired, with "stack" as a word)
- If 2 seconds has passed. This will handle the "last word". (e.g no space after)

So, to sum up, here's how it would fire as i'm typing:

> "**Stack**  " (req #1 fired - "Stack")
>
> "**Overflow** " (req #1 fired - "Overflow")
>
> " **Rocks**" (req #3 fired - "Rocks")

Hopefully that makes sense.

So, off the top of my head, i'm thinking i would need to hook into the `.keypress()` event (i'm using jQuery BTW), and then do some string magic (e.g look for spaces, etc)

Is it that simple? Or is there something out there (e.g an "extended" `.keypress()`handler) that has already done this?

Comment: You should probably see if waiting 500ms after pressing space before firing is more user-friendly (like hover-intent). You should obviously also check if they've pressed a double space, or maybe firing with the empty word is ok. Not sure if waiting 2 seconds is important, just use onblur.

Comment: @davin - yep, certainly, i'll be experimenting. Just looking for general advice on how to approach this, in terms of which jquery events to hook into. (keypress, keydown, keyup, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I would :

- Register to the input keyup event `$("input").bind("keyup", function(e){  });`
- Check if the pressed key is the space bar `if(e.keyCode == 32)`
- If it is, get the last word from the input `$("body").trigger('input_update', { last-word: false, word: $(this).val()).replace(/[\s-]+$/,'').split(/[\s-]/).pop() });`

For the 2s timer, just launch a timer when the page is ready, and reset it each time the keyup event on the input is triggered. Reaching, those 2s, the function executed should be like that : `function(){ $("body").trigger('input_update', { last-word: true, word: $(this).val()).replace(/[\s-]+$/,'').split(/[\s-]/).pop() }); }`

And before all that, register to your custom event : `$("body").bind("input_update", function(e, data){ // do your stuff with the last word });`

The code may not be 100% correct since i'm tired, but you got the idea.

Comment: Nope, don't really get it...i mean i get the idea, but not sure how to put all those code blocks into a workable piece of javascript..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if something like that is done already, but there is an easy way to sort it out, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KLhx/1/).

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps you could provide some info about your solution? (e.g how it works)

Comment: Basically, it compares sets of words before user's messing with value and after that. After he or she gets his or her hands off keyboard (timeout on 'keyup' stuff) you check (by words (split) or by whatever tokens you need to check) what has changed and use that how you see fit.

Comment: Concerning spaces: second argument of setTimeout could be changed to `e.keyCode == 32? 0 : 500`.